# Saving python array print to .csv

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

I am trying to save an array to a csv file with the code below but unfortunately, the positions are incredibly jumbled. This is the csv code i used:

```
myFile = open('colontumorpls20.csv', 'w', newline='')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(X_pls)
print("Writing complete")
```

and this is the array output i'm trying to save:

```
(array([[-9.33928690e+00,  1.96746648e+01, -4.02267914e+00,
         1.30996036e+01, -1.14971527e+01,  3.35040260e+00,
        -7.07673639e+00, -1.10222760e-02, -2.64398391e+00,
        -6.94691632e+00,  8.30183629e+00, -5.70570388e-02,
        -6.41267395e+00, -2.30140281e-01, -9.40844791e+00,
        -1.59052684e+00, -1.67466109e+00,  6.84407461e+00,
         3.71143528e+00, -1.36062438e+00],
       [-1.84182873e+01, -1.30493413e+01,  8.53445889e+00,
        -1.16116223e+01,  3.89171575e+00,  2.82551732e-03,
         2.53109522e+00,  2.38083958e+00,  3.71888084e+00,
         1.14610702e-01,  3.81203624e+00, -4.50944037e+00,
        -1.96515355e+00,  3.36169124e+00,  1.54732521e+00,
        -1.79905380e+00,  2.47811475e+00,  2.64955224e+00,
        -3.27034487e+00,  3.07457722e+00],
       [ 7.23674133e-01,  4.66693107e+00, -1.43887091e+01,
        -1.39713208e+00, -1.00000265e+01,  1.34244721e+00,
         6.65271047e-01,  5.27815424e+00, -3.24578404e+00,
         9.83654255e+00,  5.80655592e+00, -1.35387741e-02,
        -8.68814837e-01, -4.38021379e-01, -2.29711347e-01,
         7.90948586e+00,  2.15074328e+00, -3.00112296e+00,
         4.77331530e+00, -1.29848716e+00],
       [-6.65763398e+00,  7.34073699e+00,  1.12467125e+01,
        -5.63285626e+00, -8.70206725e+00,  8.72512445e+00,
        -1.26080409e+00, -2.45663863e+00,  3.98550140e+00,
        -7.49958566e+00, -1.00606223e+01, -5.33373441e+00,
        -4.03625885e+00, -1.49116863e+01,  3.43266830e+00,
        -8.14575857e-01,  4.63664511e-01,  2.38106195e+00,
         1.97097307e+00,  5.35786741e+00],
       [ 2.70853805e+01, -2.65782247e+01, -2.89003417e+01,
        -6.96432737e+00,  4.92828980e+00, -1.64912505e+01,
         3.34765055e+00,  3.69643981e+00, -1.16099780e+00,
        -1.24343002e+01,  4.49465256e-01, -8.50148866e+00,
        -2.37056027e-01, -1.72566480e+00, -8.56387726e-02,
         3.15145817e+00, -3.15008596e+00,  1.23057154e+00,
        -8.38903644e-03,  1.79314932e+00],
       [-1.35502646e+01, -8.62868966e+00,  4.01852489e+00,
        -4.92250535e-01,  5.67967849e+00, -2.89874555e+00,
         4.28258532e+00,  2.06235940e+00, -7.58926333e-01,
         5.78668897e+00,  4.27917089e-02,  4.31373794e+00,
         5.86052053e+00, -3.34867230e+00, -3.01281538e+00,
        -1.12924108e+00, -2.86500870e-01,  8.56512955e-01,
         3.01878127e+00, -2.02428914e+00],
       [-9.72283903e+00, -4.71290606e+00, -6.14914931e+00,
         1.49666569e+00, -9.56020685e+00,  6.24267217e+00,
        -7.81900908e+00, -1.28299245e+00,  4.13534979e+00,
        -1.85946821e+00,  6.43134866e-01,  4.49680275e+00,
         4.07626498e+00,  6.31401992e-01,  5.17766131e+00,
         5.65862149e+00, -4.39801018e+00, -6.40143200e+00,
        -4.54473030e+00,  2.41617808e+00],
       [ 9.21891292e+00, -3.54407663e+01,  1.05473019e-01,
         8.56150166e+00, -8.22617716e+00,  2.09485388e+00,
        -2.91818045e+00,  6.32021221e+00,  5.43102140e+00,
         8.78958597e-03, -2.60291844e+00,  8.01204813e-01,
         1.24005404e+01,  6.42808386e+00, -6.34759578e+00,
        -4.54788375e+00,  1.91446234e+00,  7.49984091e-01,
        -3.28492906e+00,  5.75404660e+00],
       [-2.05079029e+01, -1.14176704e+01,  8.58531848e+00,
        -8.35381122e+00,  9.21691836e+00, -3.09349557e-01,
        -1.93871904e+00,  2.52397824e+00, -1.42143415e+00,
        -1.11955761e+00,  1.18208008e+01,  8.63186175e-01,
        -7.38741589e+00,  3.47350113e+00, -3.77700947e-01,
        -9.37405984e-02,  2.49257917e-01, -2.76688099e+00,
        -1.15499562e+00,  4.31177611e+00],
       [ 7.73884129e+01, -2.52722888e+01,  1.35627781e+01,
        -4.49568636e+00, -5.13316415e+00,  2.94542275e+00,
        -5.24556365e+00, -8.69166595e-01,  6.70488981e-01,
         9.08754396e+00,  4.96101276e+00,  2.26327236e-01,
        -5.01676232e+00, -5.63013430e+00, -4.99156615e-01,
        -2.22566516e+00, -1.40026823e+00, -2.18776105e+00,
        -5.07761616e-01, -4.02273051e+00],
       [-4.43045846e-01,  1.59997841e+01,  1.46752514e+01,
        -1.33846645e+00, -2.39603221e-01, -5.07115866e+00,
         1.36754482e+01,  3.78008804e-01, -2.03299595e+00,
        -7.62577177e+00, -6.51182244e+00, -1.81630250e+00,
         1.59750123e+00,  4.26267170e-01, -5.01029512e+00,
         9.74340108e-01,  2.62150361e+00, -7.50000626e+00,
        -3.77560756e+00, -9.46305878e+00],
       [-4.20395669e+00, -4.53713883e+00,  1.27707808e+01,
         1.90931060e+00,  5.07394543e+00, -4.71531207e+00,
        -4.53873731e+00, -1.81323514e+00, -2.73139701e+00,
        -3.73472346e+00, -1.81591488e-01, -2.51773257e+00,
         1.46401978e+00, -5.15013143e+00, -6.09780264e+00,
         2.98170143e+00,  2.89172720e+00, -1.82923978e+00,
         4.13289192e+00,  5.78402781e-01],
       [-4.10068533e+00, -1.04535659e+01,  2.38816765e+00,
         1.78183110e+01,  3.58057080e-01, -7.55106746e+00,
         2.47157887e+00, -9.98733197e-01,  1.31962048e+01,
         6.16849010e+00, -5.92818392e+00, -8.61225955e+00,
        -5.45176172e+00,  7.53865949e+00,  3.49848614e+00,
         3.56980815e+00,  4.50171936e+00,  2.55110969e+00,
         3.52199181e+00, -4.45242966e+00],
       [-4.50247218e+00,  1.86021551e+01, -1.33310732e+01,
         4.40224292e+00, -4.46418111e+00, -3.49984469e+00,
        -1.99236904e+00,  8.65154540e+00,  1.86435784e+00,
        -2.34811664e+00,  1.98216274e+00,  3.12745258e+00,
        -3.38029659e+00, -5.67574470e+00,  3.90874929e+00,
        -8.40443614e+00,  1.00363115e+01, -8.66049560e+00,
         1.78709719e+00,  2.59307841e+00],
       [-4.23306318e+00, -8.23400862e+00, -8.72464020e-02,
         3.69324268e+00, -6.29446858e+00,  1.03686601e+01,
         1.51029964e+01, -1.11874506e+01, -3.60943178e+00,
         2.02231153e-02,  9.28544421e+00, -8.77104855e-01,
         1.22396301e+00,  3.05383792e+00,  4.44874142e+00,
         3.72977307e+00,  4.89541564e+00,  1.72003605e+00,
        -3.70904995e+00,  1.04061513e+00],
       [-8.05593780e+00, -6.82485680e-01,  7.25321973e+00,
        -7.02346326e+00, -6.71699772e+00, -1.46315922e+00,
        -5.22999401e+00, -1.92780204e+00,  1.01693806e+00,
         7.05237248e-01, -2.76508040e+00, -4.36973413e+00,
         3.90602161e+00, -5.05608572e+00,  3.09964070e+00,
         5.03739633e-01, -4.02331700e+00,  2.86543217e+00,
         3.10323367e+00,  2.50247872e+00],
       [ 1.51394559e+01, -1.14895096e+01,  3.30944224e+00,
        -7.11604161e+00,  4.23722501e+00, -7.66199223e-01,
         2.91246934e+00,  1.05913949e+00,  6.53631238e-01,
        -6.06402895e+00, -2.21272159e+00,  1.69001580e+01,
        -1.32064196e+00,  8.72618927e+00,  3.15324215e+00,
         4.08908667e-01,  5.32321036e+00,  6.57990304e+00,
         6.11965313e+00,  1.24606163e+00],
       [-9.68780165e+00, -2.58325130e+00, -8.48466726e+00,
        -4.93404071e+00, -5.55071307e+00,  9.80128760e+00,
         7.51224642e+00, -6.36743923e+00, -3.39566871e+00,
         1.29038632e+00,  6.70675106e+00, -6.93317101e+00,
         5.32731006e+00,  9.14968568e-01, -1.95305041e-01,
        -5.84731336e+00, -1.15928944e+00,  1.42353369e-01,
         5.19154958e+00, -3.69838005e+00],
       [-2.75570464e+01, -2.18835059e+01,  5.78547982e+00,
         2.17265947e+00,  5.62773740e+00,  1.84843456e-01,
        -6.21936134e+00,  7.01777614e-01,  3.05472093e+00,
         2.93362407e+00,  3.05358797e+00,  5.40070502e-02,
        -8.97128277e-01,  6.07557113e-01, -1.83643683e+00,
         5.20351175e-01, -3.97779771e+00, -3.29394205e+00,
        -1.19759492e+00,  2.01228813e+00],
       [ 1.02060759e+01,  1.11146685e+01, -2.05540889e+01,
        -6.39682013e+00,  1.39511984e+01,  1.64059041e+01,
        -6.74509187e+00, -1.44650467e+01,  3.78599833e+00,
         2.39836117e+00, -9.93700426e+00,  8.01359881e-01,
        -1.71256455e+00,  2.18499984e+00, -6.16075170e+00,
         2.34332746e-01,  3.64846999e+00, -1.86362027e+00,
        -9.98012977e-01,  7.82233199e-01],
       [-8.14201912e-01,  4.13569093e+00,  3.68748365e+00,
        -1.36891880e+00, -7.00318731e+00, -3.40662941e+00,
        -2.58880455e+00,  8.72231855e-02, -1.34497784e+01,
         5.02439576e+00, -1.30513909e+01, -3.96900118e+00,
        -3.91922636e+00,  1.71495690e+01,  1.83986486e+00,
        -2.64408172e+00, -3.77584665e+00, -2.94954569e+00,
         3.24751636e+00,  4.55825074e+00],
       [-2.94061059e+00,  2.66399108e+01, -5.08177777e+00,
         1.49642263e+00,  4.23403877e+00,  4.27041337e-01,
         3.31559583e+00,  1.13084474e+01, -4.45894701e+00,
         1.28436258e+01, -5.11610202e+00,  2.71561006e+00,
         4.99145490e-01, -9.36712866e+00, -1.98188979e+00,
         4.00569646e+00,  8.77413782e-01,  4.89031076e+00,
        -4.13291654e+00,  3.71869263e+00],
       [-4.85905853e+00, -1.84802413e+01,  6.45907176e+00,
         1.01640112e+00,  1.32273120e+01,  5.92624384e+00,
         2.84611895e+00,  4.95583103e+00, -3.99511471e+00,
        -7.06311067e-02, -4.16782706e-01, -3.66701848e+00,
         9.56861458e-01, -3.37399923e+00, -1.20865442e+00,
         2.89384185e+00,  1.29662426e+00, -1.35304915e+00,
         3.11521828e+00,  1.26348529e+00],
       [ 8.69484873e+00, -7.05317626e+00, -2.72486719e+00,
         1.39144206e+01,  8.38815956e+00,  1.87034073e+01,
         6.94603608e+00,  1.07895394e+01, -2.31028700e+00,
        -7.23340506e+00, -3.77194352e+00,  2.88279358e+00,
        -1.60817134e+00, -1.02054472e+00,  4.94959242e+00,
        -1.63995774e+00, -7.74308224e+00,  5.87896186e-01,
        -6.22861561e-01, -4.66691819e+00],
       [-1.24505826e+00,  6.26445563e+00,  2.18168962e+00,
        -1.01355353e+01, -1.11156602e+01, -4.21705499e+00,
        -3.95088713e+00,  9.54529361e-01, -2.43815851e+00,
        -3.77069795e+00, -4.02477924e+00,  3.60663472e+00,
         4.68079220e+00, -7.36800578e-01,  1.02827728e+00,
         2.83909568e+00,  4.34116100e+00,  3.25964830e+00,
        -2.43559389e+00, -5.92367151e+00],
       [-1.97086619e+01, -7.23725200e+00, -1.23997932e+00,
        -1.09503707e+00, -4.63747950e+00, -3.88709623e+00,
        -9.44565387e+00, -2.72292865e+00,  1.82815404e+00,
        -3.52615192e+00, -8.05673330e-01,  8.12410724e+00,
        -4.79854634e+00,  1.58431830e+00, -1.61185426e+00,
         2.23685468e+00, -4.57057107e+00, -1.65562880e+00,
        -3.16613738e+00, -6.42421109e+00],
       [-1.65530313e+01,  6.12585972e+00, -6.40441310e+00,
        -3.50337495e+00,  5.71858839e+00, -1.03444852e+01,
         2.64305370e+00, -5.62841753e+00,  4.21351667e+00,
         6.89731853e+00,  3.18109375e-01,  4.79680430e+00,
         3.65083472e+00, -5.25224080e+00,  3.16541537e+00,
        -4.72274443e+00, -6.42391559e+00, -1.84393213e-01,
         6.33141321e+00, -5.44219297e+00],
       [-1.00480340e+01,  3.72880066e+00, -6.67988673e+00,
        -6.91085789e+00, -1.70025468e+00, -3.41670391e+00,
         3.81543406e+00,  2.48581289e+00,  1.21577106e+00,
         5.51594086e+00, -8.76072523e-01, -2.53804326e+00,
        -4.86858441e+00,  1.81651485e+00, -7.97131142e-01,
        -5.57113334e+00, -9.65851390e-01,  5.19240261e+00,
        -1.10179556e+01, -3.58640954e+00],
       [ 1.19294013e+01,  3.24861964e+00,  2.14577817e+00,
         1.49036452e+01,  4.57714543e-01, -1.44333548e+01,
         9.86841447e+00, -1.40223314e+01, -3.37406801e+00,
         1.88013630e-01, -3.17095390e-01,  6.58088370e+00,
        -1.44858728e+00, -6.36420634e+00, -1.51442004e-01,
        -1.01643285e+00, -2.75904200e+00, -6.89762866e-01,
        -3.59680956e+00,  8.54504470e+00],
       [ 9.98874570e+00,  2.26927833e+01,  4.05948639e+00,
         9.31181409e+00,  1.29030652e+01, -4.06960017e+00,
        -1.94943526e+01, -3.60172082e+00, -7.15743910e+00,
        -1.99237648e+00,  5.05886819e+00, -4.93383662e+00,
         6.34607492e+00,  1.08976039e+00,  6.93516352e+00,
        -1.08691484e+00,  3.87479144e+00,  2.78977386e+00,
        -3.66483055e+00, -3.64645958e+00],
       [ 2.67739722e+01,  6.74989615e+01,  7.27976202e+00,
        -5.02599898e+00,  2.94769574e+00,  1.98752834e-02,
         4.52827001e+00,  3.72108733e+00,  9.41387699e+00,
        -2.59406103e+00,  6.33722706e+00, -1.64160665e+00,
         3.33979386e+00,  9.29388150e+00, -1.17219828e+00,
         1.51569235e+00, -5.25635148e+00, -9.53742724e-01,
         1.06345096e+00,  4.46163647e+00]]), array([[-4.29541479e-01,  2.74236931e+01,  3.27622429e-01,
         1.40331189e+01, -1.43118114e+01,  3.70445048e+00,
        -1.15046157e+01, -6.15384454e-02, -2.52400275e+00,
        -7.78044983e+00,  1.01949379e+01, -3.21369569e+00,
        -5.99666968e+00, -1.61141629e+00, -8.47470322e+00,
        -1.23860228e-01, -3.91126059e+00,  9.38085927e+00,
         4.93420525e+00,  3.46259015e+00],
       [-1.26800283e+00, -3.52424498e+00,  1.20200778e+01,
        -5.59627880e+00,  3.66316551e+00, -2.07643697e+00,
         2.69783395e+00,  4.55359360e+00,  5.15417792e-01,
        -8.84040789e-02,  2.92135263e+00, -4.80524104e+00,
         9.72423652e-01,  1.22188689e+00,  7.10317105e-01,
         6.79991177e-01,  6.01099876e-01,  2.38638009e+00,
         1.80267729e-01,  3.04229373e+00],
       [-7.01429145e+00, -7.34528976e+00, -1.54866658e+01,
        -4.15295948e-01, -7.63194722e+00,  3.47109180e+00,
         2.63100292e+00,  7.64515720e+00, -6.95321874e+00,
         1.05870993e+01,  5.66606433e+00,  3.97035192e-01,
        -7.53971152e-01, -2.93410261e+00, -1.19633480e+00,
         5.92919909e+00,  4.06794065e+00, -4.30351669e+00,
         4.41340519e+00, -1.74130651e+00],
       [-9.67565192e+00, -9.84295959e-01,  8.81358831e+00,
        -8.08008489e+00, -8.13305074e+00,  9.07870337e+00,
        -2.52432487e+00, -1.59952053e+00,  3.68491288e+00,
        -8.42832118e+00, -1.02066789e+01, -5.23381993e+00,
        -4.34831417e+00, -1.51078053e+01,  2.60567257e+00,
        -3.78148222e-01,  3.18683493e+00,  1.81919896e+00,
         5.72934146e-01,  5.05922229e+00],
       [ 3.10085110e+01, -2.51168466e+01, -2.96702796e+01,
        -7.93951903e+00,  5.49417651e+00, -1.62556712e+01,
         2.57995247e+00,  3.28696676e+00, -9.07340285e-01,
        -1.30863331e+01,  7.23441093e-01, -8.69962827e+00,
        -1.98468978e-01, -7.78054063e-01, -1.74205844e-01,
         3.82469682e+00, -2.87111575e+00,  1.48140457e+00,
         2.12535738e-02,  2.51590398e+00],
       [-3.31083901e+00, -9.19008072e+00,  3.14972059e+00,
        -1.55364982e+00,  4.92044930e+00, -6.60799820e+00,
         4.82905892e+00,  3.29279050e+00, -2.50198925e+00,
         3.80602867e+00, -1.90544152e+00,  3.60474540e+00,
         5.12337113e+00, -3.79401072e+00, -3.41094269e+00,
         3.71975797e-01,  1.74424833e-01,  9.15432100e-01,
         2.90126840e+00, -3.90452941e+00],
       [-4.21166474e-01,  1.81668563e+01, -6.99823619e+00,
         2.23903944e+00, -1.72547577e+01,  4.59591633e+00,
        -1.46849096e+01, -1.63460258e+00,  8.91420688e+00,
        -5.29596196e-02,  1.71396918e+00,  3.91595890e-01,
         4.80506423e+00, -2.31712266e+00,  9.52058686e+00,
         7.93129926e+00, -8.99369108e+00, -2.00755279e+00,
        -4.86465612e+00,  6.38092328e+00],
       [ 4.51708221e+00, -4.74967811e+01,  1.84124695e+00,
         7.63868988e+00, -7.42021564e+00,  3.50830377e+00,
        -2.95718521e+00,  6.73811195e+00,  4.74738351e+00,
        -1.46432233e+00, -1.86395813e+00,  1.87795081e+00,
         1.26411150e+01,  8.10412503e+00, -8.05660130e+00,
        -4.61265615e+00,  4.58469201e+00, -1.04505502e-01,
        -4.22518245e+00,  4.44536514e+00],
       [-3.14986301e+01, -2.63226644e+01,  9.24798051e+00,
        -9.89983748e+00,  7.10743393e+00,  2.11595155e+00,
        -6.30097770e+00, -5.66913026e-01,  4.60351112e-01,
        -1.66601736e+00,  1.24105473e+01, -8.89759923e-01,
        -7.73063368e+00,  2.42764442e+00, -2.61453674e-01,
        -5.02400949e-01,  1.18663000e+00, -3.16777016e+00,
        -2.33352434e+00,  3.92400075e+00],
       [ 8.15611997e+01, -2.13637888e+01,  1.41387873e+01,
        -4.42526709e+00, -5.57919482e+00,  2.64008426e+00,
        -6.19893384e+00, -1.20553834e+00,  1.09857894e+00,
         8.76154505e+00,  5.20218991e+00, -2.85678459e-01,
        -4.81819309e+00, -5.36819487e+00, -3.10460956e-01,
        -1.46997066e+00, -2.02324362e+00, -1.68744034e+00,
        -5.31936790e-02, -3.10589872e+00],
       [ 6.09523344e-01,  1.26500817e+01,  1.57181470e+01,
        -8.47218600e-01, -1.27587453e+00, -3.15836175e+00,
         7.48477335e+00, -9.00057517e-01, -2.52677794e+00,
        -7.51034031e+00, -3.97477125e+00, -3.81990388e+00,
         2.49917316e+00, -2.01176512e+00, -3.73434702e+00,
         1.65426476e+00,  2.37874137e+00, -4.58818325e+00,
        -3.06828393e+00, -4.51426110e+00],
       [ 2.00765951e+00,  2.26360247e+01,  4.01717784e+00,
         4.44111780e-01,  5.34032462e+00, -2.12451322e+00,
         2.23292120e+00,  6.07899187e-01,  2.05640130e+00,
        -9.77188625e-01, -1.26533522e+00, -1.26367901e+00,
         1.84605880e+00,  2.65437377e-01, -4.35417046e+00,
         1.87723624e+00,  8.89013213e-01, -3.40882112e+00,
         1.29391371e+00, -3.40717518e+00],
       [-7.44528487e+00, -1.17892240e+01,  1.69208941e+00,
         1.79775701e+01, -8.91461237e-01, -8.49455848e+00,
         1.13712849e+00, -2.60085185e+00,  1.44259338e+01,
         6.76469453e+00, -6.59875779e+00, -8.88526507e+00,
        -5.57277556e+00,  6.33793495e+00,  4.18662521e+00,
         3.67173268e+00,  3.94584023e+00,  2.54397891e+00,
         3.58766219e+00, -5.17570138e+00],
       [-1.96859879e+00,  2.06924321e+01, -1.21720417e+01,
         4.46058901e+00, -3.20346259e+00, -4.35845599e+00,
         7.61542371e-01,  8.86056128e+00,  1.34268767e+00,
        -2.89295775e+00,  1.68957118e+00,  4.34905094e+00,
        -3.72608181e+00, -3.66676296e+00,  3.26776642e+00,
        -8.61870530e+00,  9.93705357e+00, -9.05840718e+00,
         2.13077511e+00,  1.54400260e+00],
       [ 5.61596002e+00, -4.90239647e+00,  1.68932854e+00,
         4.72568139e-01, -3.37447735e+00,  1.24009756e+01,
         1.86090676e+01, -9.69740471e+00, -3.69839395e+00,
        -3.19381972e+00,  1.07277079e+01,  4.66175924e-01,
         8.01431840e-01,  1.04026084e+01,  2.17611753e+00,
         4.30746231e+00,  6.77499288e+00,  1.06409105e+00,
        -4.77822168e+00,  7.33135444e-01],
       [-1.25275809e+01, -9.89747558e+00,  1.12302896e+01,
        -5.61001086e+00, -4.99034246e+00, -2.82726123e-01,
        -3.70758894e+00, -3.11347210e+00, -1.34289823e+00,
         5.86360342e-01, -1.05087536e+00, -2.99068595e+00,
         3.66796678e+00, -3.88284407e+00,  3.06238583e+00,
        -1.49904181e+00, -4.06447703e+00,  4.24543990e+00,
         3.77163381e+00,  2.84927854e+00],
       [ 1.23286019e+01, -6.58986315e+00, -4.71633646e-01,
        -7.59501567e+00,  3.33345356e+00, -2.14882244e-01,
         9.65368996e-02,  4.54672790e-01,  2.08514097e+00,
        -3.98071055e+00, -1.18735080e+00,  1.63843467e+01,
        -1.20461713e+00,  6.90432089e+00,  5.52621323e+00,
         6.31724981e-02,  4.58853373e+00,  8.86239673e+00,
         5.54288464e+00,  3.84022845e+00],
       [-2.18628083e+01, -5.36614081e+00, -1.49951470e+01,
        -3.69975753e+00, -6.54746679e+00,  6.17001352e+00,
         5.65722856e+00, -9.64095464e+00, -9.45064589e-01,
         4.87199011e+00,  4.10647032e+00, -5.09270804e+00,
         5.64969747e+00, -3.35313420e+00,  1.98335126e+00,
        -6.01858926e+00, -1.50153898e+00, -9.60326750e-02,
         5.42248752e+00, -6.57776747e+00],
       [-3.01444464e+01, -1.54061391e+01, -1.54299653e-02,
         6.10391176e-01,  1.19006300e+01,  4.50669878e+00,
        -5.24042136e+00, -1.24093844e+00,  1.71271132e+00,
         5.34439649e+00,  3.57362312e+00, -1.53975849e+00,
        -2.34324944e+00, -1.52085263e+00, -8.43963686e-01,
        -2.06197405e+00, -5.49282903e+00, -4.02249903e+00,
         5.30352847e-01,  8.40480196e+00],
       [ 1.10321450e+01,  9.03833042e+00, -1.88564146e+01,
        -5.63379983e+00,  1.44150439e+01,  1.73759093e+01,
        -6.73348897e+00, -1.47139417e+01,  2.71108397e+00,
         2.06649472e+00, -9.66718466e+00,  7.72519704e-02,
        -1.64691784e+00,  1.76750720e+00, -6.51724738e+00,
        -8.06604116e-02,  3.22715288e+00, -2.11822605e+00,
        -3.01276116e-01,  1.46289459e+00],
       [ 4.90972240e+00,  8.50934665e+00,  4.21646921e+00,
        -2.08406892e+00, -7.12792772e+00, -3.34301081e+00,
        -2.30223490e+00,  7.11127658e-01, -1.30563460e+01,
         4.02920582e+00, -1.29196155e+01, -4.30626022e+00,
        -3.87128065e+00,  1.87504338e+01,  1.38827389e+00,
        -1.82399311e+00, -3.80667776e+00, -3.07024889e+00,
         3.11345866e+00,  4.69648422e+00],
       [-2.68146957e-01,  2.88209582e+01, -6.90405289e+00,
         1.30683668e+00,  3.99283524e+00,  1.96584510e-01,
        -1.79466077e-01,  8.48417844e+00, -2.01718292e+00,
         1.30006070e+01, -4.62367257e+00,  3.36818065e+00,
         1.70472312e+00, -8.34630654e+00, -1.29649288e+00,
         5.71547640e+00,  9.53864333e-01,  5.73823625e+00,
        -3.65643247e+00,  4.07776181e+00],
       [-1.27170528e+01, -2.63504548e+01,  1.63514034e+01,
         2.02213188e+00,  9.24515300e+00, -1.38822468e-01,
         3.37015150e+00,  6.48982695e+00, -4.77134402e+00,
        -1.78145556e+00, -4.66635806e-01, -2.18685038e+00,
        -5.08397710e-01, -4.08270501e+00, -2.38003713e+00,
         3.23214689e+00,  1.80036045e+00, -5.72197225e-03,
         3.19179149e+00,  1.14824329e-01],
       [ 8.43127699e+00, -6.10139464e+00, -4.16138054e+00,
         1.49499467e+01,  1.05642123e+01,  2.09610984e+01,
         1.04029872e+01,  1.11732856e+01, -3.30998891e+00,
        -6.47714063e+00, -4.65826910e+00,  2.88633394e+00,
        -1.41358940e+00, -7.17350799e-01,  4.37116482e+00,
        -3.01615436e+00, -8.30158808e+00, -1.64372931e+00,
        -2.77345338e-01, -6.18101529e+00],
       [-7.91875491e+00,  5.56929292e+00,  4.65458199e+00,
        -8.88963998e+00, -9.95705590e+00, -3.32653377e+00,
        -1.21664194e+00, -9.54823742e-01, -2.89487861e+00,
        -3.11988494e+00, -6.10465209e+00,  1.57328627e+00,
         3.17309620e+00, -3.24636864e+00,  6.23915606e-02,
         9.83552580e-01,  1.84555217e+00, -3.74419874e-01,
        -4.56251971e-01, -5.91504841e+00],
       [-2.46301104e+01, -2.85314426e+01, -9.00907573e-03,
        -1.14238599e+00, -1.09769251e+00, -9.74325258e+00,
        -3.24674230e+00, -1.54927428e+00, -7.00332828e-01,
        -6.21512509e+00, -3.46036227e+00,  1.59312207e+01,
        -4.34089746e+00,  6.37946122e+00, -5.79671378e+00,
         3.19763079e+00,  1.53204926e+00, -4.52170182e+00,
        -3.89817124e+00, -1.61570207e+01],
       [-8.82150694e+00,  1.25884592e+01, -2.02291123e+00,
        -4.62981939e+00,  4.31967254e+00, -6.50096186e+00,
         5.78222961e-01, -4.22991550e+00,  5.46931986e+00,
         4.81838526e+00,  3.10313451e+00,  2.62030262e+00,
         4.30118567e+00, -2.08566081e+00,  2.27628082e+00,
        -3.53875022e+00, -6.60787334e+00,  4.42320840e-01,
         5.75854750e+00, -2.18643823e+00],
       [-1.61630425e+01,  1.30116951e+01, -1.00535154e+01,
        -9.03228917e+00, -3.63526053e+00, -2.79343970e+00,
         6.21198022e+00,  4.76150591e+00,  3.34661321e+00,
         7.47557695e+00, -5.58485625e-01, -2.82937012e+00,
        -6.41663102e+00,  2.28276665e+00,  1.26366083e+00,
        -7.63466753e+00, -1.89488152e+00,  6.35816741e+00,
        -1.38403455e+01, -3.65968511e+00],
       [ 3.11365681e+00, -4.11945798e+00,  2.58269537e+00,
         1.77187137e+01,  4.36580500e-01, -1.61084275e+01,
         1.06905031e+01, -1.45212628e+01, -5.13196870e+00,
         1.85123718e+00, -2.10012927e+00,  6.83180142e+00,
        -1.53435435e+00, -1.07758817e+01, -8.18031125e-02,
        -2.23157405e+00, -3.36063107e+00, -1.90260554e+00,
        -2.33947272e+00,  7.09252730e+00],
       [ 8.65025663e+00,  1.65077468e+01,  3.18263959e+00,
         9.00868721e+00,  1.32061513e+01, -3.94239575e+00,
        -2.12457709e+01, -3.28800157e+00, -8.13321347e+00,
        -2.20213433e+00,  5.44991210e+00, -4.82290244e+00,
         6.67709469e+00,  4.25488014e-03,  6.82048544e+00,
        -7.81251858e-01,  5.28145292e+00,  3.32596113e+00,
        -3.91196923e+00, -3.04887628e+00],
       [ 2.42998615e+01,  6.47830643e+01,  6.94287197e+00,
        -5.80845560e+00,  4.49271700e+00, -1.25533311e+00,
         8.07241057e+00,  4.45933394e+00,  8.84419798e+00,
        -3.04605646e+00,  5.12925435e+00,  1.05928445e-01,
         2.56264136e+00,  1.07519572e+01, -2.33181547e+00,
         9.52560866e-01, -4.12642146e+00, -2.48248503e+00,
         6.37485022e-01,  1.92848520e+00]]))
```

Using PCA.fit_transform, the excel result is usually neat and clean- making the whole text -> column process much easier. But PLS_fit_transform made my .csv looks like this as the end result:

[Outputs written in .csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI9ZN.png)

20 supposedly-columns suddenly turned into 5. Are there any easier way to organize the writings? I'd very appreciate it.

Comment: Your array output is actually a tuple of two arrays. Is that what you want to bring to the csv file, or is that an error?

Comment: What I really want to bring to the csv file is writing one [...] for each row but the result i obtained is one tuple for each row. While I can pretty much paste the it (the details in the image i attached) into column, I'm still losing half of the content of my output.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "the result i obtained is one tuple for each row". The data you pasted is one giant tuple containing two `np.array`s. Obviously, one tuple with two arrays will not be neatly turned into a csv file. Maybe what you want is to bring each array in the tuple as a csv file separately? Or to merge the arrays so that you have one single array to convert to csv?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. My apologies beforehand, I'm actually having difficulties explaining this kind of thing considering english isn't exactly my main language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as pointed out by @OriolMirosa, your output is a tuple of two arrays. Perhaps you intended to stack them? You'd do (I'm making up the data for clarity)

```py
import numpy as np

two_arrays = np.random.random((2,8,20))
data = np.hstack(two_arrays)
```

so that each array in `two_arrays` has 8 rows and 20 columns, while the resulting `data` has 8 rows and 49 columns.

You can then save the single array using `np.savetxt`:

```py
np.savetxt('colontumorpls20.csv', data, delimiter=',')
```